# nodejs + express : make http request wait for udp response

Tags: node.js, express, udp

I am a **nodejs web(express) application**, when **someone(UI)** sends a get request to me ,I **send a udp request** to another guy and expect a reply from him, and when the udp server(part of me) receives the reply from him, I sent it back as httpresponse to the the guy who  sent me httpget request.

1. how to make httprequest wait until a udp response received?
2. how to set communication between udp server and my controller/action method which has got a httpget request.

I have tried 'setTimeOut' function, but request doesn't wait for it.

I am calling this sendMessage from the my controller/action:

```
   module.exports.sendMessage = function (ip, port, message) {
        var msg = new Buffer(message);
        var dgram = require('dgram');
        var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

        client.send(msg, 0, msg.length, port, ip, function (err, bytes) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            console.log('UDP message sent to ' + ip + ':' + port);
            client.close();
        });
    }
```

controller/action code:

```
router.get('/getSomething', function (req, res) {
   //calls send message from here
}
```

udp server code which runs at all time from the time application started:

```
server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
    console.log(remote.address + ':' + remote.port + ' - ' + message + message.length);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code? How are you making the udp call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code to

```
module.exports.sendMessage = function (ip, port, message, res) {
    var msg = new Buffer(message);
    var dgram = require('dgram');
    var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

    client.send(msg, 0, msg.length, port, ip, function (err, bytes) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        console.log('UDP message sent to ' + ip + ':' + port);
    });

    client.on('message', function(msg, rinfo) {
      client.close();
      res.send(msg);
    });
}
```

And you can call it like

```
router.get('/getSomething', function (req, res) {
  sendMessage('x', 'z', 'y', res);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but i guess didn't explain it well.
i need to send res.send() when i receive a udp(response) message from the guy i sent the udp message. 
I am asking for some data through udp, and when i receive it, i need to send it to other system.

Comment: @user1179299 sorry. I updated the code, see if is that what you need